# POST method from AngularJS to Symfony

Tags: php, angularjs, post, symfony

Could someone please help me with a POST method from angular to symfony?
I use symfony as backend and I'm trying to add a new user from angular with ngResource.

My factory:

```
app.factory('sveKlupeServiceFactory', ['$resource',
 function($resource){
var data = $resource('xxxxxx', {klupa: '@klupa'},{
 query: { method: 'GET', isArray:false},
 save : {
        method : 'POST',
        url : "//api-dev.steora.com/control-board/smartbenches",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-ww-form-urlencoded'
        },            
    }
 });
 return data;
```

}]);

My controller:

```
  .controller('klupeController', ['$scope', 'sveKlupeServiceFactory', function ($scope,sveKlupeServiceFactory){
sveKlupeServiceFactory.query(function(res){
$scope.klupe = res.smart_benches;
});
$scope.setDataForKlupa = function(klupaID){
    $scope.currentKlupa = sveKlupeServiceFactory.get({klupa: klupaID});
};

$scope.addKlupa = function(){ sveKlupeServiceFactory.save($scope.addKlupa););};
```

In chrome console and firebug console, I got

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested       resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.
```

Back end add this in header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

The GET work just can't get post to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: hi, i fix this, the problem was in backend, but now i have another problem. My json file looks like this: serial_number=dsfsdfsdfsdfs&location_id=dfsdf&token=sdfs&type=standard&description=sdfsdf [] []    but i need it to looks like this  {"token": "asdgfasdfghasdfgsdf", "type":"standard","description":"opis pametne klupe","location_id":111,"serial_number":"000012-U","time_zone":"Europe\/Parddfgis","is_active":1,"last_ip":"192.169.1.5"}.  and i got 400 error